# how to encrypt parts of image in least significant bits of another image?

Tags: image-processing, rsa

I want to encrypt some parts of image and embed them into least significant bits of another image.I have pictures in the form of small picturebox in  windows forms c#.Can anyone help me with encrypting these blocks?

Comment: Please provide more information about what you have already tried and what error you are getting

Comment: I did it once using matlab and it was quite straight forward. Just cast your images as matrix and swap their less significant bit of each pixel

Comment: I have an array of bitmaps and i want to encrypt each bitmap and then embed them into lsb's of image.I m new to encryption and any help regarding is considered.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: we don't provide tutorials or a research service here. please do your own research and try to solve the problem. show what you've got and we'll help you do the next step. also read [ask] and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Sometimes I don't understand why y'all are so mean.

Comment: Thanks @ Sneaky Polar Bear I wish everyone could think from your perspective !    I m trying to hide an array of bitmaps into lsb of another image.But problem is in reading of array of bimaps and then extracting it.Be it a simple bitmap I would be able to embed n extract but problem is in array of bitmaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it is the correct or fastest way, but likely the easiest way is to just use modulus operator.  So for instance if you want to squeeze 2 images into one which has greyscale data in byte format (0-255).  For simplicity lets assume you want an even split of 4 bits per image. 2^4=16.  So if you take every pixel in that image and mod it:

```
pic1Pixel = pic1Pixel -pic1Pixel %16
```

that is going to peel the bottom significance out of that image.  Then in the other image do this:

```
pic2Pixel = floor(pic2Pixel /16)
```

Do whatever you need to do (casting and floor or whatnot) to ensure the operation happens and then is rounded correctly (language dependent).

Then simply add your two bitmaps pixel by pixel.

```
compoundPixel = pic1Pixel + pic2Pixel
```

If after that you want to pull out the first image:

```
pic1Pixel = 16*(floor(compoundPixel/16))
```

second image:

```
pic2Pixel = 16* (compoundPixel%16)
```

There is almost certainly a cleaner way to do it with simple bit shifting, but I don't feel like debugging/testing anything right now and don't know the sintax off hand.  In short though you would just shift in the first 4 bits from first pic then the first 4 bits from the second pic.  To recall you would shift out appropriately or mask and normalize.